# Why is this member of this Struct not printing out (C Programming)

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list, structure

in the code below 'netAddr' pointed to by 'root' prints put but not the 'maskAddr' pointed to by 'pointer. Thanks in advance, only asking as a last resort. The value of 'netAddr' prints off, but anything pointed by 'pointer' doesn't.

```
struct RouteInfo
{
unsigned long netAddr;
unsigned long gateAddr;
unsigned long maskAddr;
char ifName[IF_NAMESIZE];
int metric;
int ttl;
    struct RouteInfo *next;
};

   struct RouteInfo *root; /* This will be the unchanging first node */

    /* This will point to each node as it traverses the list */
    struct RouteInfo *pointer;

    //allocating space for the root
    root = malloc(sizeof(struct RouteInfo));
    root->next = 0;
    root->netAddr = 19216811;

    //Point to 1st Item
    pointer = root;

    /* Creates a node at the end of the list */
    pointer->next = malloc( sizeof(struct RouteInfo) );
    pointer = pointer->next;
    pointer->maskAddr = 25525500;

    pointer->next = malloc( sizeof(struct RouteInfo) );
    pointer = pointer->next;
    pointer->gateAddr = 19216810;

    pointer->next = malloc( sizeof(struct RouteInfo) );
    pointer = pointer->next;
    strcpy(pointer->ifName, "eth1");

    pointer->next = malloc( sizeof(struct RouteInfo) );
    pointer = pointer->next;
    pointer->metric = 16;

    pointer->next = malloc( sizeof(struct RouteInfo) );
    pointer = pointer->next;
    pointer->ttl = 30;

    //marking the last as NULL
    pointer->next = 0;

    //Pointer points to root again
    pointer = root;
        printf("%lu%lu \t",root->netAddr, pointer->maskAddr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you do not assign to `root->maskAddr = ;`

after:

```
root = malloc(sizeof(struct RouteInfo));
root->next = 0;
root->netAddr = 19216811;
```

add:

```
root->maskAddr = 25525555;
```

and its working:

```
:~$ ./a.out 
19216811 25525555
```

Here you can find your working code: [**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/ZPMy9hck)

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea how I can get the 'ifname' printing out?
So far i've assigned it like this "strcpy(root->ifName, "dtfdty");" and "root->ifName, "dtfdty";" but none of them work as the compiler says they're incompatible.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working before, I should have tried more first, thanks for all your help.

Comment: @ACScStudent---- No its working with your string too at  [Codepad](http://codepad.org/V5BmGAQB) You may have other mistake

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize `root->maskAddr`.

Answer (score 1):

As NPE said, you never valued `root->maskAddr`. So maybe you mean this?

```
printf("%lu%lu \t",root->netAddr, pointer->next->maskAddr);
```